# como puedo quitar algo que esta escrito en un header en la pagina de busqueda de wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

tengo un problema en wordpress en la pagina de resultados de busqueda cuando yo busco un producto esta pagina me muestra una texto de esta forma, inspeccionando me di cuenta que hay algo escrito en el header que es como lo muestro en la imagen pero no encuentro como puedo quitar eso escrito, muchas gracias por leer mi pregunta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probablemente hay (o había) un plugin para realizar las búsquedas mediante peticiones AJAX o es un error del tema. Intenta desactivando los plugins de Woocommerce para identificar cuál es el culpable.

Comment: verifica si es algún plugin, haz una copia y testea los plugins de a uno, también prueba con otro tema para verificar que el tema no sea el problema, si es cosa del cosa instálate el plugin "What The File" para verificar que archivo .php es el que estas viendo, rastrea el archivo e intenta verificar en que parte sucede, si no tienes mucho conocimiento lo mejor es que contrates a un desarrollador, suerte!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podría ingresar a la sección de Personalizar el Tema en cuestión, desde ahí en caso sea muy concreto puedes rastrear mediante su clase tenga o no algún span como etiqueta para darle el display:none

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo suelo utilizar para estilar bloques puntuales que pueden ser complejos de hacerlo per se dentro de lo que es WordPress. Concluyo en que esta podría ser una alternativa para tu caso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]